# How to update md5 in raw r package?

Tags: r, md5

I download some package, i.e "xxx.tar.gz",then I unpack it and modify some source file in it,finally I pack it into zip file.After that I try to install it locally in RStudio,then it gives me error message `file 'R/xxx.R' has the wrong MD5 checksum` where `'R/xxx.R'` is modified file. So how to address this problem. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yap, that is how R ensures the integrity of a package. If you really what to  modify a package locally (detached from its developer), I think the best way might be to locate the file containing the `md5` sum from the package, replace it with a new `md5` which you compute locally (you can compute an md5 for the modified package locally). I wouldn't do an md5 replacement for a package that I don't maintain, not sure about the problem you tackle or face on the way or while using the package.

Comment: @deepseefan Thanks.I just found the solution.Just use `md5sum from tools package ` compute md5 of modified file then use such new md5 to replace old md5 in md5 file